# Get SelectedItems from database fed ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, datarowview

I need to get values from selected items from listbox which is binding from database. But if I try

```
listBoxAtribute.SelectedItems[0].ToString()
```

it returns `System.Data.DataRowView`

Is there any way to convert Data from `DataRowView` to `string`?

My idea looks like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < listBoxAtribute.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
{
  MessageBox.Show(listBoxAtribute.SelectedItems[i].Tostring);
}
```

Thanks a lot for any reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting selected item of listbox to DataRowItem first and access columns value passing column name to indexer

Here is  the sample

```
((DataRowView)Listbox.SelectedItem)["<column_name>"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show fist column value, then take fist item of listBoxAtribute.SelectedItem as

```
for(int i = 0; i < listBoxAtribute.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
{
  MessageBox.Show(listBoxAtribute.SelectedItems[i].Item[0]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] items = listBoxAtribute.SelectedItems.Select(x => x.Item[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that you are seeing, visibly that is, a single specific column from said database driven entries, that would indicate that you have the `DisplayMember` property of the listbox set.  Possibly the `ValueMember` as well, assuming you are using EditValue anywhere.  I would write something along these lines.

```
((DataRowView)listBoxAtribute.SelectedItems[0])[listBoxAtribute.DisplayMember].ToString();
```

That way you get exactly what the user would see on the screen.  Now, if you want a different piece of data than the one shown on the screen, you would need to use user968441's approach and hard code the column name.  But that's also relatively easy.