# Listbox Selection: DataRowView to Type Sting is not Valid

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable, listbox, oledb

I'm working on populating a listbox with a datatable that is being filled from a database. Here is the relevant code.

```
Private Sub frmMainMenu_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Load data we need from the database
        Dim commandCraneType As New OleDbCommand("SELECT Name FROM CraneType WHERE Girders = 'Single Girder'", gConnection)
        Dim adapterCraneType As New OleDbDataAdapter(commandCraneType)
        Dim dTableCraneType As New DataTable()
        'Fill datatables and controls
        adapterCraneType.Fill(dTableCraneType)
        lboCraneType.DataSource = dTableCraneType
        lboCraneType.DisplayMember = "Name"
End Sub

Private Sub lboCraneType_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lboCraneType.SelectedIndexChanged
        'Set the gCraneType global variable!
        gCraneType = lboCraneType.SelectedItem
        Debug.Print(gCraneType)
End Sub
```

The listbox properly populates with the text values in the Name field from the database. However when I select that item in the listbox, the debug tells me that gCraneType has been assigned System...DataRowView, and I get an exception saying I cannot cast that type to a String. I do not understand why the Names are showing up properly in the listbox but the selections are a data type.

Thanks for any help you offer :)

Comment: dTableCraneType is a DataTable.  The SelectedItem is a DataRow not a DataTable.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006741/windows-forms-listbox-selecteditem-displaying-system-data-datarowview-instead and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117932/get-selecteditems-from-database-fed-listbox and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428542/why-i-get-system-data-datarowview-instead-of-real-values-in-my-listbox

Comment: How should I change what I'm doing to set gCraneType to the selected text in lboCraneType?

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. @Chris Your references were very helpful. I'm posting an answer just in case anyone else stumbles over my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
Private Sub lboCraneType_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lboCraneType.SelectedIndexChanged
        'Set the gCraneType global variable!
        gCraneType = lboCraneType.SelectedItem
        Debug.Print(gCraneType)
End Sub
```

To:

```
Private Sub lboCraneType_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lboCraneType.SelectedIndexChanged
        'Set the gCraneType global variable!
        Dim drv As DataRowView = lboCraneType.SelectedItem
        gCraneType = drv("Name").ToString
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help in the commnets.